# which laser color printer with duplex function works out of the box on ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, printer, duplex

I'm searching for a printer with the following characteristics:

- network support (e.g. 10/100 Mbit)
- laser
- color
- duplex unit
- above features must work on Ubuntu 10.04 out of the box (<< that's why I'm asking here)

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain, but in my experience, the HP line color laserjets have the best linux support.  Specifically the 4600/4650 series that I have experience with.  You'll probably want the [hplip](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) package, which I believe is in the Ubuntu repos.